# Android - BasicNetwork.performRequest: response code 501

Tags: android, android-volley, mopub

I'm trying to use MoPub in my Unity game. I'm getting this annoying response code 501 when trying to request an ad. I'm using MoPub test id's (but same with the real ones). this is my logcat yelling at me:

E/Volley: BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 501 for http://ads.mopub.com/m/ad?v=6&id=agltb3B1Yi1pbmNyDAsSBFNpdGUY6tERDA&nv=3.4.0&dn=PANTECH%2CIM-A800S%2CVEGA_IM-A800S&ll=41.7220194%2C44.7301424&lla=39&llsdk=1&z=%2B0400&o=p&sc_a=2.0&mr=1&mcc=282&mnc=02&iso=ge&ct=2&av=0.1&android_perms_ext_storage=1&udid=mp_tmpl_advertising_id&dnt=mp_tmpl_do_not_track

All i know is the data is sent via GET, so the link looks fine. 501 means the server does not know what's the request is about. The mopub comments say that the response code never goes out of {[200-299], 304} range and this puzzles me even more. please, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try this link in a normal browser already? First the browser displays a mopub picture and then comes with a message that the browser does not understand the mopub protocol. `mopub://finishLoad`.

Comment: I had tried in chrome and it only displayed the test image. now I tried in safari and it said 

**safari can't open "mopub://finishLoad"**

Comment: Try FireFox like i did.

Comment: Are you still having problems with this question?  If you solved it yourself, please post the answer, or delete the question if you no longer need an answer.  Thanks.

Comment: I haven't solved it. I just changed the ad server but I'm still interested in this issue.

Comment: That ad unit id (`agltb3B1Yi1pbmNyDAsSBFNpdGUY6tERDA`) doesn't look correct to me.  I'm seeing all my ad unit id's as hex strings, so there should be no characters outside of [0-9,a-f].  Are you sure you copied the ad unit id correctly out of the portal?  Can you post the code you use to setup the MoPubView?

Comment: You're using the MoPub test ID?  Where did you get it from?  I can't find any test ID's for MoPub..........?  Cheers

Comment: oh, hey, we got test app or something set up but I'm not sure :)) I'm just requesting id's from our administrator and get everything running, then I substitute the id's. but that was then, now we just put the real id's straight away.
by the way this turned out to be a bug at mopub and they got it fixed not sure when. all's working with the latest mopub unity plugin.